# Blocked port 5000?

Tags: firewall

I am trying to use my Ubuntu laptop with a Heroku hosting (it's a kind of VPS hosting).

Their support says my port 5000 is blocked. Any way I can check it? Does it make any sense?

Is it my pc, or my router? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of torrent clients that have built in port checkers, utorrent used to host a site but it no longer does. http://www.canyouseeme.org/ has a quick and dirty one, but it has to be run from the desktop via a webbrowser (servers need to get dirty with `wget`).

You can also issue these commands to see what is listening on you ports locally:

```
sudo lsof | grep TCP                #All TCP connections
sudo lsof | grep TCP | grep isten   #All Listening TCP connections
sudo lsof | grep ip                 #All ipv4 or ipv6 connections
sudo lsof | grep :5000              #All connections to or from port 5000
```

The only caveat is that lsof uses named ports by default so that last command wont work with `:80` but will work with `:http`